# how to get the admin's home nodeRef in alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, nodereference

I want to add a space in admins home with java in alfresco
 so i'm trying to use this code:

```
serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService().create(adminhomeRef,"Some space name",ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER);
```

The problem is that i don't khow how to get the reference of admin's home so how do i do it or is there any service who provides this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked the `PersonServiceImpl` class of Alfresco API, and I saw these lines that can be useful for you:

```
NodeRef person = personService.getPerson("your_username");

NodeRef homeFolder = (NodeRef)DefaultTypeConverter.INSTANCE.convert(NodeRef.
this.nodeService.getProperty(person, ContentModel.PROP_HOMEFOLDER));
```

Can you test if this is what you need?

Comment: Please don't post answers to ask for clarification of the question, instead post a comment. If you cannot post comments yet, then wait until you have 50 rep to do so.